# Multiple NuSOAP clients causes "Undefined index: _transient" error

Tags: php, soap, phpunit, nusoap

I'm working with 0.9.5 and I'm doing some phpunit tests.

When I execute my second test, that invokes again the webservice, I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined index: _transient

/var/www/dev_folder/nusoap/nusoap.php:227
/var/www/dev_folder/nusoap/nusoap.php:7293
```

when

```
$client = new nusoap_client($this->_config->URL_Path . $webserviceWSDL, true);
```

is executed by a second time.

I checked nusoap.php and seems something related with globals or something static or singleton... but I don't know what can I do to solve the problem...

```
$GLOBALS['_transient']['static']['nusoap_base']['globalDebugLevel'] = 9;
```

Need nusoap client to be unloaded or something like this? Why this global variable is failing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  The comments seemed to indicate that the global variable was an attempt to emulate a static class variable, so I simply updated the code to actually use a static class variable in the `nusoap_base` class.  That seemed to do the trick.

You can checkout the code [here](https://github.com/developagility/NuSOAP/commit/c51bdd96b993b5a6103428db69b26b25abb4337b).